# How to sign off a patch using git

Tags: git, msysgit, git-patch

I'm working on a project where some people will sent me git patches and I've to verify those patches and sign off the commits.

We are creating the patches using

```
git format-patch master --stdout > file.patch
```

And the file is mailed to us, then we've to verify the patch. For this we creates a new branch and then applies the patch to that using

```
git apply file.patch
```

Then verifies the contents of the commit, if it is correct then we need to add sign off to each commit from the patch.

I've seen the git -am command where we can add the signoff at the time of applying the patch.

Is it possible to add a commit after applying a patch?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a commit after applying a patch?

Well, yes, you just make some changes and create a new commit.